# calculating the volume of a room with a lopsided ceiling

Tags: volume

Part of my job description requires that I find the volume of a room for calculating air leakage. Normally no problem, but this is an unusual house for many reasons. The main issue I'm having a problem with is that I don't know how to calculate the volume for a room where the ceiling slopes in two directions.

I knew that I'd have a problem with describing the room so I included a small example to illustrate the room i'm trying to find the volume of.

[image: lopsided ceiling example]
[image: lopsided ceiling]

Would you also show the work, and/or at least provide a formula so that I can apply it on the job?? Thank you

Comment: Is the ceiling flat or curved? In the first case it seems the room isn't even rectangular ...

Comment: Are the walls orthogonal to the floor? And I think we're missing a measure on the depth of the room.

Comment: right. sorry guys, this is just an example. assume the depth is the same as the width. and yes, the ceiling is flat, and the walls are orthogonal.

Comment: Without going too deep into massive measurements and modeling, I suppose a good approximation can be obtained by taking the average $\frac{9+9+10+11}4=9.75$ as height ... (And if the base assumptions - rectangular floor, vertical walls, flat ceiling - are correct, this gives even the exact result)

Comment: would an average actually work on this?? I had not thought of that...

Comment: @JacobHooper Yes, it would - however, if you have 10 and 11 in front, you cannot have 9 and 9 in the back (under these assumptions) - only 9 and 10 or 8 and 9 or the like, i.e., with the same difference

Comment: alright... one moment then, because I might need a little more help. I'm going to show the proper scan...

Comment: edited original question to include proper floor plan

Comment: are the 6'1 1/4" and 14'3" walls parallel?

Comment: and the 14'3" and 21' 6 1/4" walls orthogonal?

Comment: and i think there's one wall length missing, the small bit between the 6'1 1/4" and 14'3" walls

Comment: the wall length that is 19' is made up of the 12' section from the nook and the 7' section that includes the slope down and the flat wall.
 the 14'3" and 21'6 1/4" are orthogonal. and the 14'3" and 6'1 1/4" are parallel

Comment: Got it, actually was able to infer that from the lengths you gave eventually.

Comment: Linking to a [more general case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628540)

Answer (score 1):

I get a total volume of around 16,654 cubit feet.

See my schematic:

[image: schematic]

Hopefully it's legible enough.

Basically, we put the floor onto a coordinate plane of our choosing. Since the upper right corner is the only right angle at an extreme of the room, I chose that as the origin.

We then find the coordinates of all the corners of the room, and express the height of the ceiling as a plane; the volume of the room is then the double integral over your floor plan of that plane.

The double integral is simplest when splitting into trapezoidal regions; I couldn't see how to use less than 4 (labeled $A,B,C,D$ on the graph).

We need to use the Pythagorean theorem to find the coordinates of two points: the bottom of region $B$ and the bottom of region $C$. The equations used are to the right of the schematic.

We solve for the plane describing the height of your ceiling by using the general formula for a plane, $f(x,y)=ax+by+c$ and plugging the three points whose heights we know to find $(a,b,c)$. If we use three points you told us: $(0,0,0), (-25,-35.5,11), (-11,-38.15,10)$, we get $(a,b,c)\approx(-.072,-.005,9)$, but this is inconsistent with your saying that we also have $(-25,0,9)$ (because $f(-25,0)\approx 11$). I'll assume the 9 is wrong, for now; the procedure from here is the same once we've figured out the plane for the height of the ceiling:

Finally, we integrate:

$$V=\intop\intop_A f(x,y)dydx+\intop\intop_{B}f(x,y)dydx+\intop\intop_{C}f(x,y)dydx+\intop\intop_D f(x,y)dydx$$

$$V=\intop_{-25}^0\intop_{-17}^0f(x,y)dydx+\intop_{-31}^{-25}\intop_{-.187x-34.29}^{-16.5}f(x,y)dydx+\intop_{-25}^{-11}\intop_{-40.23-.189x}^{-17}f(x,y)dydx+\intop_{-11}^{-7}\intop_{20.01+5.29x}^{-17}f(x,y)dydx$$

I plugged those integrals into Wolfram Alpha ([e.g.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+-.72x-.005y%2B9+over+x%3D-25+to+-11%2C+y%3D-40.23-.189x+to+-17)) to get the final approximations and added them.

---

EDIT:

In fact, with some care taken we can [get WolframAlpha to give us the answer in general](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral%5Ba*x%2Bb*y%2Bc%2C%7Bx%2C-25%2C0%7D%2C%7By%2CMax%5B-.189*x-40.23%2CMin%5B20%2B5.29*x%2C-17%5D%5D%2C0%7D%5D%2BIntegral%5Ba*x%2Bb*y%2Bc%2C%7Bx%2C-31%2C-25%7D%2C%7By%2C-.187*x-34.29%2C-16.5%7D%5D) in terms of the $(a,b,c)$ which describe your roof by using $\max$ and $\min$ to describe the lower boundary (otherwise the query is too long for the website):

$$V(a,b,c)=-12781.8a-13824.9b+820.356c$$

So once you settle on which heights to use to describe your roof, solve for $(a,b,c)$ and plug it in to that simple equation.

Comment: But the ceiling can't be planar, given the dimensions in the diagram. It must be curved, and we don't know how it's curved. So we can't possibly calculate the volume of the room.

Comment: OP says "roof is flat" in the comments

Comment: Yes. But that is impossible, given the heights in the diagram.

Comment: He's saying 11' and 10' "assumed". I'll leave it to OP to say which of the measurements we should trust more.

Comment: But how did you get your answer, if the input data were inconsistent?

Comment: ignored the fourth height (9 ft at (-25,0)) and found the plane through the others. Actually looks like that's pretty far off; we'll have to wait for an update from @JacobHooper.

Comment: Indeed.${}{}{}$

Comment: See edit. Regardless of if the ceiling is flat, the procedure is essentially unchanged. Just need to change $f$; even if it's curved, he clearly doesn't need to be correct to 4 decimal places; an approximation by a plane should suffice. It's just a matter of prudently choosing which plane to use.